# how to use sudo python -m on ubuntu (20.04)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to do a `python -m flask run` command at the terminal because the interpreter packages I'm using for my projects reside in the .local user directory (which 'python -m' seems to call but simply using 'python' does not).  I'm trying to use this to open port 80 though (a privileged port) and thus need to invoke root, but when I try 'sudo python -m flask run ..." I get the "flask module doesn't exist" type of error.  How do I run this command as root and still use the .local path for my python modules?

Answer (score 3):

By default sudo runs commands in different environment.
You can ask sudo to preserve environment with `-E` switch.

```
sudo -E <command>
```

Comment: Worked!  Welcome to SO and may you bless others in the community with answers :-)

Comment: Another approach (which will be be less $HOME/.local-bound) is to create a virtual env / venv, install the packages etc you want into that, then run the python interpreter from that dir via `sudo -E`.